# I need to know how to use an album of photos in my OneDrive on Photobox?

Tags: onedrive

I have an album of photos on OneDrive ( all from my Lumia camera) that I wish to use on PhotoBox but no idea how to get them there without downloading each imndividually and then uploading them again onto Photobox - any quicker way? I use a Chromebook but can get access to a PC with a disc or USB stick option if needed?